# Batch Export selection of PDF files from Acrobat with no user interaction?

Tags: pdf, automation, adobe

I'm using Acrobat Pro DC and have set up an Action to Export PDF to DOCX format, which is the format I need for import into another app.

I have specified the files I wish to include in the batch.

However, I have to click the following buttons for each file:

1. Proceed
2. Export (defaults)
3. Recent Folder (same for all files)
4. Save (defaults)

Is there a way to not have to be present whilst it does these conversions?

My plan B is to use Keyboard Maestro to click the buttons for me so that I can simply press a single hotkey for every export. But I still need to be there.

Comment: Have you tried *Automator* ?  I have neither *Acrobat* nor *Microsoft Word*, but I understand they come with *Automator* actions that might be able to do this file processing for you.

Comment: @CJK yes, I've looked into Automator but the only action in there from Acrobat is *Save as Adobe PDF*.

Comment: I need Acrobat to do the conversion as it is very good at it, better than FineReader or any other program I have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is: using JavaScript in an Action List.

This is what I ended up with...

JavaScript:

```
var newfile = this.documentFileName.replace(/\.pdf$/i, "") +".docx";
this.saveAs(newfile, "com.adobe.acrobat.docx");
```

Action List:

[image]

Works well. i can press Start and then go away and it will do the whole batch without any human input.

The only annoying thing is that the window keeps regaining focus between each file, even if I hide it. The workaround for that is to put Acrobat in a Space of its own.